# How to find the second largest value within certain row?

Tags: sql

I have two tables, movies(id, name, year, rating) and movies_genres(movie_id, genre), I want to find the id of all second top rated movies within each genre(not global), but when I wrote this

```
select MG.genre, M.id
from movies_genres MG inner join movies M on MG.movie_id = M.id
where M.rating = 
(select max(rating) from 
(select rating from movies M2 inner join movies_genres MG2 on M2.id = MG2.movie_id where MG2.genre = MG.genre) 
where rating < 
(select max(rating) from 
(select rating from movies M3 inner join movies_genres MG3 on M3.id = MG3.movie_id where MG3.genre = MG.genre)))

order by MG.genre;
```

I got an error, it said that the MG.genre in Line 5 is a invalid identifier.

Comment: please tag the database you are using

Comment: Try aliasing your derived tables.

Comment: Try changing your 'from movies_genres MG' to 'from movies_genres AS MG', IF that works...alias the others as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a database other than `mysql` you can use `row_number` window function to get the second highest rated movie for each genre.

```
select MG.genre, M.id
from movies_genres MG 
inner join movies M on MG.movie_id = M.id
inner join (select m.*,mg.*,
            row_number() over(partition by mg.genre order by m.rating desc) as rn 
            from movies m inner join movies_genres mg on mg.movie_id = M.id) x
on x.id = m.id and mg.genre = x.genre
where x.rn = 2;
```

Comment: I think you need to join on genre in addition to movie_id

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to make a reference to the outer genre, only to the next select level like this:

```
Select MG.genre, M.id
From movies_genres MG, movies M 
Where M.id = MG.movie_id
And M.rating = (Select max(rating)
    From movies M2, movies_genres MG2
    Where M2.id = MG2.movie_id
    And MG2.genre = MG.genre
    And rating < (Select max(rating)
        From movies M3, movies_genres MG3
        Where M3.id = MG3.movie_id
        And MG3.genre = MG2.genre)
    )
order by MG.genre;
```

Edited: oopsie, I've missed one reference to genre: `And MG2.genre = MG.genre`. Just added.

How does it work? The most inner select returns the max rating of the ask genre MG2. The middle select returns the max rating of asked genre MG, which is lower than the max of most inner select. The outer select list all movie ids (and genre) with this exact rating.

Comment: inner join syntax is better than ,

Comment: Yes, but comma version is shorter and you can better show what the problem/solution is. Both variants should work.